# Delayed or Asynchronous DML Trigger Execution

Tags: trigger, azure-sql-database, dml, delayed-execution

I have created a DML trigger (AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on a table
Trigger's logic takes about 30 seconds to execute

So if you change even 1 row, it takes ~ 30 seconds due to trigger execution
Developer asked me "Is there a chance that the trigger could be a fire & forget action?"

I said no, but is it really so ?

*Question:*

Can trigger be executed in "asynchronous" mode?
Application updates couple of rows in few ms, and thinks that transaction is completed, and then trigger is silently executed under the hood ?

I understand that this actually does not look good from consistency point of view, but still, is it possible ?

Comment: The trigger logic needs to be changed. Single row change causing a 30 second trigger execution is going to be a pretty huge bummer in your Azure environment.

Comment: @Zane I would not say so. Table is changed rarely, and btw it does not matter 1 row or 8 million rows change. It will be +30 sec due to trigger in each case, and the time is not critical to Application at all

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6380/sql-agent-job-dependencies-with-table-driven-solution/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware this is not possible with the **triggers** feature of Azure / SQL Server. One reason likely being, as you mentioned, it breaks the [**Consistency**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) property of the **ACID** principals of a database:

> ...any data written to the database must be valid according to all
> defined rules, including constraints, cascades, triggers, and any
> combination thereof. This prevents database corruption by an illegal
> transaction...

**Triggers** are meant to fire transactionally in lockstep with the operation that caused them to fire. Imagine if the row of data that the **trigger** was dependent on was deleted before the **trigger** got to execute asynchronously. This could get you into a lot of trouble.

Alternatively, you can have a **trigger** that simply adds a row to a queue table, and a **SQL Agent Job** for example, that constantly runs checking that queue table and firing a **stored procedure** with the logic from your original **trigger** to emulate an asynchronous event. Perhaps that would improve your workflow?

Comment: thanks for response J.D.!  I edited my question, it is Azure SQL DB, not SQL Server 2017. Added later by mistake

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko Gotcha, no prob! Likely the answer is almost exactly applicable just as well to Azure SQL DBA too.

Comment: going to mark as answer, waiting to get 1 vote up on the Question. Hope to get Socratic badge at least by 2030 :D

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko May the badge be yours lol. :)